# hide subsections from toc

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I tried to hide certain subsections (Hello) in the table of contents. I didn't find a solution that worked. I use the article class. Do you know what command I might use?
Thanks for you help!

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, inner=1in, outer=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{acronym}
\renewcommand*\aclabelfont[1]{\acsfont{#1}}%unbold acronym

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

%Anhang

\section*{Anhang}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Anhang}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}} 

\subsection{Hello}

\subsection{Hello}

\end{document}
```

Comment: what  about `\subsection*{Hello}`?

Comment: Welcome! Can you complete the code so it can be compiled?

Comment: @touhami \subsection*{Hello} will hide the letters (numbering) everywhere. i just want them hidden in the toc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a  solution

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section*{Anhang}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Anhang}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}} 

\addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\string\c@tocdepth 1\relax}
    \subsection{Hello}
    \subsection{Hello}
\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}

    \subsection{Bye}
\end{document}
```